# searching sorting filtering not working for ng-table in angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm using ng-table for searching filtering pagination. It displays all ok. but nothing is working. It displays all records but my count is 5. Searching is not working.

Comment: post u have tried create a fiddle

Comment: It works. The data I provide not get properly. Is is necessary to give variable as data only??